# How to refetch graphql query from another component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm very new to React and especially to graphql.

I'm trying to refetch the events query everytime I use the mutation createEvent, so my page with all the events will be auto updated and won't need a refresh.

However, I can't find a way to connect with the two queries.

my mutation createEvent from "form.jsx" file:

```
  const body = {
    query:
      "mutation{" +
      "createEvent(eventInput:{num1:" +
      '"' +
      this.state.num1.toString() +
      '"' +
      ",num2:" +
      '"' +
      this.state.num2.toString() +
      '"' +
      "}){" +
      "_id " +
      "num1 " +
      "num2 " +
      "addition " +
      "multiply" +
      "}}"
  };
  fetch("https://localhost:8000/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
        throw new Error("Failed!");
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      console.log(resData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

And this is my events query from "myTable.jsx" file:

```
const body = {
  query:
    "query {" +
    "events {" +
    "_id " +
    "num1 " +
    "num2 " +
    "addition " +
    "multiply" +
    "}}"
};
//console.log(body);
fetch("https://localhost:8000/graphql", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
      throw new Error("Failed!");
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(resData => {
    const events = resData.data.events;
    this.setState({ list: events });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I tried refetchQueries function in the Promise 'then' funtion, but it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the queries from a queries.js file, and then the refetch option using ApolloClient was enabled.